# XSLT increment recursion template

Tags: templates, xslt, recursion, increment

Please help me solve increment issue.
Is there a way to make an increment numbering list without using position(), number() or xpath expressions?

Here is the sample xml document that I want to process using xslt 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <text>a</text>
    <text>b</text>
    <text>c</text>
    <line>
        <test>5</test>
        <test>6</test>
    </line>
    <line>
        <test>7</test>
        <test>8</test>
    </line>
    <line>
        <test>9</test>
        <test>10</test>
    </line>
    <line>
        <test>11</test>
        <test>12</test>
    </line>
</root>
```

What I want to get is an increment variable, that increases with each `<line>` node. 
Here is the desired output with `<pos>` increment:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<line>
  <line-item>
    <pos>1</pos>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>6</value>
  </line-item>
  <line-item>
    <pos>2</pos>
    <value>7</value>
    <value>8</value>
  </line-item>
  <line-item>
    <pos>3</pos>
    <value>9</value>
    <value>10</value>
  </line-item>
  <line-item>
    <pos>4</pos>
    <value>11</value>
    <value>12</value>
  </line-item>
</line>
```

Here is my style sheet transformation that I managed to come up with so far:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" id="1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="total_lines" select="count(root/line)" />

    <line>
        <xsl:call-template name="iter">
            <xsl:with-param name="end" select="$total_lines" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </line>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="iter">
    <xsl:param name="counter" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="end" />

    <xsl:if test="$counter &lt;= $end">
        <line-item>
            <pos>
                <xsl:value-of select="$counter" />
            </pos>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="root/line/test" />
        </line-item>

        <xsl:call-template name="iter">
            <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter + 1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="end" select="$end" />
        </xsl:call-template> 
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/line/test" > 
    <value>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </value>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the actual output, the problem is that it repeats every `<value>` in the every `<line-item>` node, and this is not what I intended to get in result.

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<line>
  <line-item>
    <pos>1</pos>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>7</value>
    <value>8</value>
    <value>9</value>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>11</value>
    <value>12</value>
  </line-item>
  <line-item>
    <pos>2</pos>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>7</value>
    <value>8</value>
    <value>9</value>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>11</value>
    <value>12</value>
  </line-item>
  <line-item>
    <pos>3</pos>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>7</value>
    <value>8</value>
    <value>9</value>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>11</value>
    <value>12</value>
  </line-item>
  <line-item>
    <pos>4</pos>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>6</value>
    <value>7</value>
    <value>8</value>
    <value>9</value>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>11</value>
    <value>12</value>
  </line-item>
</line>
```

I read through the topics all over the internet and it seems that i'am stuck. 
Please help me.
P.S. Sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view a strange solution, but changing one line will do:

Change from:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="root/line/test" />
```

To:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="root/line[$counter]/test" />
```